# Trying to get a printf statement to execute once in a bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am wondering how I would go about having the

```
printf "Credentials found!"
```

just once when multiple credentials are found.

[image: Screenshot]

```
Attempting Dictionary Attack on 192.168.91.130

Credentials Found!

Log into the telnet server by running telnet -l admin 192.168.91.130

When prompted enter the password found 'admin'

Credentials Found!

Log into the telnet server by running telnet -l sfx 192.168.91.130

When prompted enter the password found 'toor'
```

The `bash` loop:

```
for i in "${!user[@]}"; do
    printf "The Username & Password is %s : %s\n\n" "${user[i]}" "${pass[i]}" >> SSH-Credentials.txt

    printf "${NCB}Credentials Found!${NC}\n\n"

    printf "Log into the SSH server by running ${YELLOW}ssh ${user[i]}@$ip${NC}\n\nWhen prompted enter the password found ${YELLOW}'${pass[i]}'\n"
    printf "${NC}\n"
done
```

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: Why does the picture say telnet but the script says ssh?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a test on `$i` as in:

```bsh
    [[ "$i" -lt 1 ]] && printf "I am only printed once\n"

    # OR
    (( i < 1 )) && printf "I am only printed once\n"

    # OR
    ! (( i )) && printf "I am only printed once\n"

    # OR
    [ "$i" -lt 1 ] && printf "I am only printed once\n"

    # OR
    if [[ "$i" -lt 1 ]]; then
        printf "I am only printed once\n"
    fi
```

Assuming you do not use *associative bash array*.

In short: *If index is less then 1, then print.*

---

For the sake of readability I would also have broken up those lines. Way to wide. Note that you can also say:

```
printf '%s %s some long text' \
"$var1" "$var2"
```

Using capital letters for variables is also a bad habit.

Information should also normally be printed on *`stderr`*, so `>&2`.

Would also have used:

```
prinf '%s@%s' "${user[i]}" "$ip" >&2
```

instead of:

```
prinf "${user[i]}@$ip" >&2
```

Answer (score 0):

Output the header if the `user` array has elements in it.

```bsh
if [[ ${#user[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    printf '%sCredentials Found!%s\n\n' "$NCB" "$NC"
fi
```

Then do your loop.

```bsh
for i in "${!user[@]}"; do
    printf 'The Username & Password is %s : %s\n\n' "${user[i]}" "${pass[i]}" >> SSH-Credentials.txt

    cat <<END_MESSAGE
Log into the SSH server using ${YELLOW}ssh ${user[i]}@$ip$NC
When prompted, enter the password found: ${YELLOW}${pass[i]}$NC

END_MESSAGE
done
```